# After you've found an a WebDriver element, how can you apply an xpath on that element to narrow it down further?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here's the situation:

My HTML code's structure looks something like this:

```
XPATH1
     XPATH1 + XPATH2
     XPATH1 + XPATH3
XPATH1
     XPATH1 + XPATH2
     XPATH1 + XPATH3
```

I need to access those sub-paths. **So I"m trying to get all XPATH1s into a list first and then trying to iterate over it.**

Unfortunately, this is yielding duplicates for me.

I've got the following code in Python:

```
elements_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH1)

for element in element_list:
    var1 = element.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH2) #We need XPATH1/XPATH2
    var2 = element.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH3)
    #lots more sub-paths
```

I suspect that what is happening is, element.find_element_by_xpath(XPATH2) **does NOT** apply to the element's XPATH. Instead it applies it universally on the page and fetches the whole list of XPATH2s.

I can't use XPATH1 + XPATH2 either because then it's still going to path to each element.

**How can I access each element on this page using a for loop?**

Also, is there any use of **element.find_element_by_xpath function**? It seems practically useless because the xpath gets applied to the entire page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you didn't specify CONTEXT NODE.

Note you should start your XPATH2 and XPATH3 with the dot that stands for *"current context"* (XPATH1):

```
elements_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div')

for element in element_list:
    var1 = element.find_element_by_xpath('./a')
    var2 = element.find_element_by_xpath('.//p')
```

This Selenium behavior inherent for search by XPath only. With other methods as `find_element_by_css_selector`, `find_element_by_name`, etc... context node should not be specified, so `element.find_element_by_css_selector('a')` will work fine

Comment: Thank you! This worked fine! In the meanwhile I solved it using a different method.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of solving this, besides the way Andersson pointed out, is the following:

```
total_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(XPATH1))

for i in range(1,total_count+1):
    var1 = element.find_element_by_xpath("("+ XPATH1 + ")[{0}]".format(i) +  XPATH2)
    var2 = element.find_element_by_xpath("("+ XPATH1 + ")[{0}]".format(i) + XPATH3)
```

Basically, we type in the absolute path by putting XPATH1 in brackets and iterating over it with an index.

Comment: Using string concatenation along with string formatting is not quite pythonic. Consider to use `"({0})[{1}]{2}".format(XPATH1, i, XPATH2)`